# Moving items in a ListBox

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox, contains

I have a ListBox that has a bunch of items in it. However, I want to be able to sort the items in the list based on a match in the Item.

So if I had some items that looked like this in the ListBox:

```
U3      IC-00276G   236.135  198.644  90   BGA48     
U12     IC-00270G   250.610  201.594  0    SOP8      
J1      INT-00112G  269.665  179.894  180  SOIC16    
J2      INT-00112G  269.665  198.144  180  SOIC16    
FID2    FIDUCIAL    5.080    24.130   0    FIDUCIAL  
FID1    FIDUCIAL    5.080    189.818  0    FIDUCIAL 
FID3    FIDUCIAL    0        112.231  90   FIDUCIAL
```

I want to be able to keep everything the same unless the item contains "FID". At which point I want to add them to the top of the ListBox and in numeric order.. so in other words the **NEW** ListBox would look like this:

```
FID1    FIDUCIAL    5.080    189.818  0    FIDUCIAL 
FID2    FIDUCIAL    5.080    24.130   0    FIDUCIAL 
FID3    FIDUCIAL    0        112.231  90   FIDUCIAL 
U3      IC-00276G   236.135  198.644  90   BGA48     
U12     IC-00270G   250.610  201.594  0    SOP8      
J1      INT-00112G  269.665  179.894  180  SOIC16    
J2      INT-00112G  269.665  198.144  180  SOIC16
```

I was going about this using something like this:

```
if (aListBox.Items.Contains("FID"))
{
    # I don't know what to put in here to make it grab the Item and move it
    # to the top of the List and also numerically ordering them.
}
```

### - Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance :)

### ***EDIT:***

```
foreach (var item in listOneLines)
    if (item.Contains("FID "))
        ListBox.Items.Add(item);
foreach (var item in listOneLines)
    if (item.Contains("FID0"))
        ListBox.Items.Add(item);
foreach (var item in listOneLines)
    if (item.Contains("FID1"))
        ListBox.Items.Add(item);
foreach (var item in listOneLines)
    if (item.Contains("FID2"))
        ListBox.Items.Add(item);
foreach (var item in listOneLines)
    if (item.Contains("FID3"))
        ListBox.Items.Add(item);
foreach (string item in listOneLines)
    if (!item.Contains("FID"))
        ListBox.Items.Add(item);
```

and the ***new*** ListBox loops like this:

```
FID1    FIDUCIAL    5.080    189.818  0    FIDUCIAL 
FID2    FIDUCIAL    5.080    24.130   0    FIDUCIAL 
FID3    FIDUCIAL    0        112.231  90   FIDUCIAL 
U3      IC-00276G   236.135  198.644  90   BGA48     
U12     IC-00270G   250.610  201.594  0    SOP8      
J1      INT-00112G  269.665  179.894  180  SOIC16    
J2      INT-00112G  269.665  198.144  180  SOIC16    
FID2    FIDUCIAL    5.080    24.130   0    FIDUCIAL    #From here down is what
FID1    FIDUCIAL    5.080    189.818  0    FIDUCIAL    #I want to be removed.
FID3    FIDUCIAL    0        112.231  90   FIDUCIAL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group or sort the items in many ways as you populate the listBox.
I've given some examples below. They're not necessaarily the most amazing solutions, but I figure that you'll learn more by seeing some of the possibilities than by giving a cryptic or "clever" solution. These also illustrate how you can insert at different locations in the list (as mentioned in the question).

A simple approach to separate the one list into two (unsorted) lists is by adding to the end or inserting at the beginning of the list (not a very efficient approach but often this won't be a relevant problem in UI code unless you have large lists):

```
foreach (string item in itemList)
{
    if (item.Contains("FID"))
        listbox.Items.Insert(0, item);  // Add at start of list
    else
        listBox.Items.Add(item);        // Add at end of list
}
```

(Note that the FID items will appear in a reversed order)

Or add the items in two passes:

```
foreach (string item in itemList)
{
    if (item.Contains("FID"))
        listbox.Items.Add(item)    // Add all items with FID in them
}
foreach (string item in itemList)
{
    if (!item.Contains("FID"))
        listbox.Items.Add(item)    // Add all items without FID in them
}
```

Or find an insertion location for every item:

```
foreach (string item in itemList)
{
    int insertPos = 0;
    bool itemIsFID = item.Contains("FID");
    while (insertPos < listBox.Items.Count)
    {
        // Primary sort - put FID items ahead of non-FID items
        bool boxItemIsFID = listBox.Items[insertPos].Contains("FID");
        if (itemIsFID && !boxItemIsFID)
        {
            // The new item must be inserted before the existing item
            break;
        }

        // Secondary sort - alphabetical
        if (item.CompareTo(listBox.Items[insertPos]) > 0)
        {
            // The new item must be inserted before the existing item
            break;
        }
    }

    // Insert the item at the location we've found
    if (insertPos < listBox.Items.Count)
        listBox.Items.Insert(insertPos, item);
    else
        listBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Or finally, you could Pre-sort a collection of the items by implementing your own `IComparer` and using your collection's `Sort` method:

```
itemList.Sort(MyComparer);
foreach (string item in itemList)
    listbox.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: Hey I am using a similar loop(s) to your second example.. however it seems to add the items twice. Once at the top and once at the bottom. I am adding an edit above and I am curious on how to remove the bottom added items

Comment: Your edit seems ok. You might improve it by using StartsWith() rather than Contains() if the text you're looking for is always at the start of the items. I can't see any reason (in what you posted) for the repeated items at the bottom of your list. Try commenting out small chunks of the code at a time to see which is responsible for the added items.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom sort using IComparer

See [this](http://codeintheoven.blogspot.com/2011/04/sort-listbox-using-icomparable-in-c.html) tutorial as an example or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort.aspx) one

Inside your custom sort method you can easily put your conditions for sorting